# extension checking not work on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is my function for checking the extension if anything is uploaded

```
$.fn.isImage = function() {
        var exts = ['.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg', '.JPG', '.PNG', '.JPEG'];
        var format = new RegExp('(' + exts.join('|').replace(/\./g, '\\.') + ')$').test($(this).val());
        if(!format){
            this.val('')
            alert('Upload file format just allow JPG and PNG!');
            return false;
        }else{
            .....
        }
    }
```

Check .MP4

```
$.fn.isMP4 = function() {
    var exts = ['.mp4','.MP4'];
    var format = new RegExp('(' + exts.join('|').replace(/\./g, '\\.') + ')$').test($(this).val());
    if(!format){
        this.val('')
        alert('Upload file format just allow MP4!');
        return this;
    }else{
        ....
    }
}
```

It works fine through all browsers except IE. Is there anyway to fix it or is there problem in my code? Please let me know if any further info is needed. Thanks!

Comment: which IE version did to you test?

Comment: @Vivek Confirmed IE 11

Comment: Tried this on IE 11 and it seems to work. Please make sure you are using the right selectors. If possible, post the DOM and how you are calling these functions.